# Laravel query builder - Union All with Skip and Take

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I need to get data from a table using this query:

```
(select columns 
   from tableX 
   join tableZ 
   on tableX.id1 = tableZ.other_id)
union all 
(select columns 
   from tableX 
   join tableZ 
   on tableX.id2 = tableZ.other_id) 
LIMIT num1, num2
```

Without the `LIMIT`, I get the correct result with my query builder that look like this (let `$first` be the first query of select and `$second` is the other select query):

```
$first->unionAll($second)->get();
```

When I try to put `skip` and/or `take`, the result is not the same as the first query above.

```
$first->unionAll($second)->take(num1)->skip(num2)->get();
```

The result query from the above builder (I got it from `DB::getQueryLog()`) is something like:

```
(select columns 
   from tableX 
   join tableZ 
   on tableX.id1 = tableZ.other_id LIMIT num1, num2)
union all 
(select columns 
   from tableX 
   join tableZ 
   on tableX.id2 = tableZ.other_id)
```

which ofcourse yield incorrect result. Does anyone knows what is the work around to make the first query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Workaround is to use raw query using DB::select and DB::raw in below sample block...

```
    $num1 = 100; // skip first 100 rows
    $num2 = 2;   // take only 2 rows 

    $qry_result = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from 
          (
            (select columns from tableX join tableZ on tableX.id1 = tableZ.other_id)
             union all 
            (select columns from tableX join tableZ on tableX.id2 = tableZ.other_id) 
          ) Qry LIMIT :vskip , :vlimit ") , array('vskip'=>$num1,'vlimit'=>$num2) 
   );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap `$firstQuery` in another query, like this:

```
$first->unionAll($second);

$rows = DB::table( DB::raw("({$first->toSql()}) as t") )
->mergeBindings($first->getQuery())
->take(num1)->skip(num2)
->get();
```

This will result in the following query:

```
select * from (FIRST_QUERY union all SECOND_QUERY) as t limit num1, num2
```

Comment: sorry for this. My question was answered long time ago and forgot to accept as narendra's answer but you got upvote for additional answer.